# Force upright Greek letters with isomath

Tags: math-mode, greek, roman, isomath

The `isomath` package makes it possible to typeset upright Greek letters via `\mathrm` and `\mathbf`. Is it it possible to force all Greek letters to be typeset upright unless specified otherwise, e.g. to make it so that `\(\Phi \Psi\)` delivers the same output as `\(\mathrm{\Phi \Psi}\)`? An ideal solution would be to load `isomath` with some option and if it optionally could make difference of upper and lower case Greek letters.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{isomath}

\begin{document}

\(\Phi \Psi\)% These are typeset in italic

\(\mathrm{\Phi \Psi}\)% These are typeset upright

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of code producing Greek letters]

Comment: Just for reference, if XeLaTeX is an option, the package unicode-math provides an easy solution to this problem through the "math-style" option, documented at section 5 of the manual.

Comment: add `\usepackage{upgreek}`, then you can write `\upPsi` for example

Comment: @AndyBarbour - I found your solution to be the least impactive for what I was trying to solve. (meaning the best solution without other side-effects)

Comment: The point of the "isomath" package is to typeset capital Greek letters in italic by default. The easiest way to achieve upright Greek by default is **not** loading isomath! "amsmath" as well as many other packages provide `\varGamma`, ..., `\varOmega` for italic Greek math letters.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need the **isomath** package:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{operators}{0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{operators}{1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{operators}{2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{operators}{3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{operators}{4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{operators}{5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{operators}{6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{operators}{7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{operators}{8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{operators}{9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{operators}{10}
```

To get an italic Gamma, use `\mathnormal{\Gamma}`. Try

```
$\Gamma\mathnormal{\Gamma}\mathbf{\Gamma}$
```

[image]

The command `\DeclareMathSymbol` is used for assigning a meaning to characters or commands in math mode. The second argument contains the "kind" of symbol; `\mathalpha` means a symbol that obeys to the alphabet selection commands. The third argument is the alphabet used by default; the fourth is the slot in the font. All the standard declarations are in `fontmath.ltx` loaded at format creation time.

Notice that these declarations won't work if the default font encoding of the document is T1 instead of OT1, as `operators` refers to the ordinary Roman document font. One should define a new math alphabet, in this case.

How to do this when the document encoding is T1? One has to define a new symbol font:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{otone}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{bold}{otone}{OT1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Gamma}{\mathalpha}{otone}{0}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Delta}{\mathalpha}{otone}{1}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Theta}{\mathalpha}{otone}{2}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lambda}{\mathalpha}{otone}{3}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Xi}{\mathalpha}{otone}{4}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Pi}{\mathalpha}{otone}{5}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Sigma}{\mathalpha}{otone}{6}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsilon}{\mathalpha}{otone}{7}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Phi}{\mathalpha}{otone}{8}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Psi}{\mathalpha}{otone}{9}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{otone}{10}
```

Of course `cmr` can be changed into the document's main font family name, provided it contains Greek uppercase letters in its OT1 version; but it's just a matter of giving the correct slot numbers for the chosen font.

Comment: I tried your solution but `\Gamma` produces italic output.

Comment: @N.N. Please, show a minimal example, as mine works. The suggested code must go *after* loading **isomath**.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pxXkGuce produces http://i.imgur.com/f92xj.png. I use Ubuntu's TeX Live 2009 if that matters.

Comment: @N.N. Sorry! I copied the wrong code!

Comment: Cheers, it works now! Do you mind including an explanation of what the lines of `\DeclareMathSymbol` does, i.e. their meaning, in your answer? Also, if there is an `isomath` solution I'd be interested to learn about it.

Comment: How about lower case? Thank you

Comment: @thone That’s a com-letely different business.

Answer (score 5):

`isomath` was written to set the math style to an 'ISO math style', as the author of the package puts it. Essentially, this means that it will be possible to typeset Greek letters 
(and non-Greek ones, for that matter) as bold italics, to denote vectors and matrices according to the ISO standard.
It is possible to have upright letters, too.
`isomath` requires OML font encoding. The `isomath` documentation (2011-01-14) states:

> Currently only the `mathdesign` package provides upright fonts in OML encoding.

So, this package also needs to be loaded in order to obtain the correct fonts. LaTeX may otherwise display entirely different characters.

An example based on code snippets from the package documentation could be:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[OMLmathrm,OMLmathbf]{isomath} % options define which alphabets will be loaded, i.e. if bold face font is not necessary, `OMLmathbf` can be ommitted.
\begin{document}
$\Gamma$ $\mathrm{\Gamma}$ $\mathbf{\Gamma}$ $\mathbfit{\Gamma}$

$\pi$ $\mathrm{\pi}$ $\mathbf{\pi}$ $\mathbfit{\pi}$
\end{document}
```

The output will be:

[image]

It seems that the definition of the new math alphabets by `isomath` can lead to an error. To circumvent this, load the package with the option `reuseMathAlphabets`.

Known incompatibilities: `fourier`package

Comment: Thanks for you answer. How does this answer my question for a way to force all Greek letters to be typeset upright unless specified otherwise, e.g. to make it so that `\(\Phi \Psi\)` delivers the same output as `\(\mathrm{\Phi \Psi}\)`?

Comment: I'm sorry if I could not give a satisfactory answer. Maybe you can define a new command: `\newcommand{\upGamma}{\mathrm{\Gamma}}`. Otherwise you need to change the fonts, as @egreg did in his answer. I'm afraid I don't have the skills to propose anything more 'general' that could substitute e.g. `\Gamma` with `\mathrm{\Gamma}`. (`\renewcommand` obviously doesn't work here.)

Comment: Note that you can specify any of the three upright families from `mathdesign` without loading the package, with, e.g. `\usepackage[OMLmathrm, rmdefault=mdput]{isomath}` for Math Design Utopia.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the [documentation of isomath](https://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/isomath/isomath.pdf), Section 2.2.1 (for the 2012-09-04 version), provides several alternatives for setting upright greek letters in math mode. The one I liked the most, because it did not require changing the fonts I was using, was option (e):

e) Use the text character with the `alphabeta` package from the `lgrx` bundle:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{alphabeta}
```

and in the body

```
$ u = 2 \text{\pi} r $
```

**Edit:** As noted by [Davislor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/61644/davislor), it is safer to use `\textnormal` instead of `\text` to prevent italics in italicized environments, such as Theorems.

```
$ u = 2 \textnormal{\pi} r $
```

Comment: You want `\textnormal` here. `\text{\pi}` will set `\pi` as italic if the surrounding text is italic, such as inside a theorem statement.

Answer (score 1):

An older font with upright Greek letters is AMS Euler. Loading `eulervm` or `eulerpx` will also set your Latin letters upright, but some packages have an option like `eulergreek` to set only the Greek letters to Euler.  The `stix` and `stix2` packages support Greek letters in `\mathrm`.  There is also an upright Greek font in `fourier`.  None of these are compatible with `isomath` or listed in its manual because they use an encoding other than OML.

The `lucidamatx` package supports `math-style=upright`.  The `mathdesign` package supports `greeklowercase=upright`.

The `kpfonts` and `mathdesign` packages support the commands `\alphaup`–`\Omegaup`.  The `upgreek` package supports `\upalpha`–`\upOmega`.  Both `newtxmath` and `newpxmath` support `\upGamma` as well as `\Gammaup`, etc.  The `fourier` package supports `\otheralpha`–`\otherOmega`.

If using `isomath`, you can either load `mathdesign` and then `\usepackage[OMLmathrm]{isomath}`, or get the math design fonts with, for example, `\usepackage[OMLmathrm, rmdefault=mdput]{isomath}` for Math Design Utopia, or load an upright OML math font with `\SetMathAlphabet`.  See table 3 in the `isomath` manual for the upright families that come in OML.  (If you load `mathdesign`, I would recommend you load `erewhon`, `garamondx` or `XCharter` afterward to fix some bugs with its text fonts.)

I would recommend you use `unicode-math` in LuaTeX when you can, and legacy math fonts when you have to.  All OpenType math fonts contain upright Greek letters that you can use with, for example, `\symup{\pi}`, `\muppi` or `\uppi`.  You can also give `unicode-math` the package option `mathrm=sym` to make `\mathrm{\pi}` an alias for `\symup{\pi}`.  If you do so, you should `\setoperatorfont` and make sure to write `\textnormal{iff}`, not `\mathrm{iff}`, for words in math mode.  Finally, you can give `unicode-math` the option `math-style=upright`.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to load `mathdesign`  *after* `isomath` since the default is uppercase greek letters in `mathdesign` (as in many other packages and classes).  I remark that the lowercase greek letters can also be made uppercase by default using `greeklowercase=upright` option to `mathdesign`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{isomath}
\usepackage[utopia]{mathdesign}

\begin{document}


\[\Gamma\Delta\Theta\Phi\Psi
  \quad
  \mathit{\Gamma\Delta\Theta\Phi\Psi}
  \quad
  \Gammait\Deltait\Thetait\Phiit\Psiit\]
```

[image: upright greek letters]