# Writing equations with fractions and greek letters

Tags: equations

I'm trying to write this equation below and using the `\usepackage{amsmath}`, but I'm getting the error *! Argument of \frac  has an extra }* so I still don't know what I did wrong. And how can I make everything upright and not italic?

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\dot{\varepsilon} = A{\prime}{\prime}{\prime}\dot\frac{\sigma\dot\omega}{k\dotT}\dot\frac{1}{d^2}\left(1+\frac{\pi\dot\delta}{d}\dot\frac{D_{KG}}{D_v} \right)
\end{eqnarray}
```

[image]

Comment: A) Don't use `eqnarray`, it is *not* `amsmath` and evil. It looks like you simply want to use the `equation` environment here. B) Italic is the usual way to typeset math (but there are packages for upright math, I assume). C) There are a few simple errors in your equation: `\dot` vs `\cdot`, `\dotT` vs `\dot T`/`\cdot T`, `A'''` vs `A\prime…`. D) I don't get your error. Can we see a minimal working example?

Comment: `\dot` should be `\cdot`, except for the first one: `\dot` produces a dot over the following symbol. For multiplication you need `\cdot`. Also `A'''` is to be used for the primes.

Comment: @egreg thanks to both of you. I removed the `eqnarray` and used `equation`  and made the changes you both pointed to. So it's working now. I still need to know how to add bold and remove italic effects to my equations.

Comment: @abdu for boldface math, you can use `\mathbf{<symbol>}`. Do you want to remove math "italicized" font for all the math expressions (that would be rather unusual), or just for some symbols?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina you know I've just checked. I just need to remove italic for the greek letters in my equation. I was just looking for a solution. There is this `upgreek` package but it's not working I think because I'm using `amsmath`. Any suggestion?

Comment: @abdu please teke a look at this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/41919/3954.

Comment: See also my updated answer.

Answer (score 6):

You are using `\dot` to express a product; `\dot` is meant to put an accent (a dot) over its argument (as in the first `\dot{\varepsilon}`); for product you can use `\cdot`.
Don't use `eqnarray`, but one of the environments provided by `amsmath` (`align`, for example). Since your example doesn't require any special alignment, I used a simple `equation` environment.
`\prime` as a superscript requires `^`; so you can write `A^{\prime\prime\prime}` or simply `A'''`.

Perhaps this is what you need:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\dot{\varepsilon} = A^{\prime\prime\prime}\cdot\frac{\sigma\cdot\omega}{k\cdot T}\cdot\frac{1}{d^2}\left(1+\frac{\pi\cdot\delta}{d}\cdot\frac{D_{KG}}{D_v} \right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Seeing the font used in the image attached to the question, it seems that the `fourier` packages was used:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\dot{\othervarepsilon} = A'''\cdot\frac{\othersigma\cdot\Omega}{k\cdot T}\cdot\frac{1}{d^2}\left(1+\frac{\otherpi\cdot\otherdelta}{d}\cdot\frac{D_{KG}}{D_v} \right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I downloaded the `fourier.sty` because it was missing. But I don't know how to let the terminal find it. Do you I have to copy it somewhere? I'm using TeXLive.

Comment: @abdu A full installation of TeX Live (from TUG, preferably) includes by default the `fourier` package. I wouldn't know how to do the installation manually. If you cannot perform a full installation of TeX Live, I suggest you to ask another question regarding the manual installation of just `fourier`.

Comment: weird I already have TeX Live 2012 from TUG. Anyways, thank you =)