# Upgreek symbol in text mode and display mode should be Roman

Tags: italic, greek

In latex ell symbol are shown to be italic font. But We want that symbol to be Roman.

I have tried in upgreek style but not yet that output.

How to get it Roman?

Comment: are any of the answers to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41907/579) helpbul?