# Upright bold greek symbols without upgreek or globally changing font

Tags: bold, boldmath

I'd like to typeset vectors as bold letters; I've tried `\mathbf` and then `\bm`, but I don't like the italicization of `\bm` and `\mathbf` doesn't work on Greek. I also really like the default, Computer Modern font.

I've read the [standard question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/54166/upright-lowercase-pi) on the subject, but the `upgreek` commands clash with Computer Modern. The package `textgreek` doesn't seem to fit the bill, because it complains if I try to put its commands in math mode. There are very many solutions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9219/upright-greek-letters-in-text-mode-not-upgreek) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41907/define-particle-names-to-use-upright-greek-letters-in-math-mode?rq=1), but all of the ones I've checked change the font of the entire document, or demand I change my LaTeX compiler. (I see one comment exchange: "But won't this change the font?" "Yes, of course.")

All I want is a few decent looking letters with as few changes or extra packages as possible. Is there a short or ideally one-line solution?

Comment: For pdflatex, my answer here should help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145926/upright-greek-font-fitting-to-computer-modern/230220#230220

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This is ingenious, thanks!

Comment: There is no upright greek in Computer Modern.

Answer (score 1):

With `unicode-math` use the option `bold-style=upright`.  Requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bold-style=upright]{unicode-math}
\begin{document}

$a,z,B,X,\alpha,\beta,\Gamma,\Xi$

$\symbf{a,z,B,X,\alpha,\beta,\Gamma,\Xi}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I would like to avoid changing to XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I'm concerned with portability and need other people to be able to easily compile my files.

Comment: @knzhou LuaLaTeX can almost be used as a drop-in replacement for pdfLaTeX.  The changes you have to make are usually only minor.