# How to switch to upright greek in math mode?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, symbols, greek

I use `libertine` and `newtxmath` font packages, they provide upright greek letters. However, there is no way to conveniently swith between italic and upright greek letters. I need a command, simillar to what is discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3535/bold-math-automatic-choice-between-mathbf-and-boldsymbol-for-latin-and-greek), to change normal greek letters to upright bold symbols.

None of the commands `\mathrm`, `\mathbf`, `\boldsymbol` or `\bm` makes`\theta` to appear as `\uptheta`. Moreover, `isomath` package does not work with the encoding and its typeface is not desired. I don't want to globally switch to upright greek letters or change the font shape.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[type1]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} 

\begin{document}
What I get: $\theta \bm{\theta} \mathrm{\theta} \bm{\mathrm{\theta}}$

What I want: $\theta \bm{\theta} \uptheta \bm{\uptheta}$ 
\end{document}
```

**--- Partial Solution ---**

I found that a new `upgreek` command may be defined to replace all greek letter macros (e.g. `\theta`) with their upside variants (e.g. `\uptheta`) in its argument. Following example does it for three greek letters. The scope of the command is local, so both variants can be used in a single equation.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[type1]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} 

\newcommand{\upgreek}[1]{{
\renewcommand{\beta}{\upbeta}
\renewcommand{\theta}{\uptheta}
\renewcommand{\zeta}{\upzeta}
#1
}}

\begin{document}
$\upgreek{\theta} \bm{\upgreek{\theta}} \theta \bm{\theta}$ 
\end{document}
```

**Questions:**

- Is it safe to patch `\mathrm` to run `\upgreek` on its argument?

Comment: Could [l2tabu](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/l2tabu/english/l2tabuen.pdf) help you? Section 2.3.6 Typesetting upright greek letters? I never used upgreek letters before so this was just a wild guess

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30550/force-upright-greek-letters-with-isomath) may be of interest.

Comment: @patrick Thanks. It suggest using 'upgreek', which does not help to switch between upright and italic greek letter.

Comment: @Jubobs I ckecked it. `isomath` is not working with `libertine`, and globally forcing greek letters to upright form is not wanted. I need `\mathrm` or any other command to modify `\theta` to appear as `\uptheta`.

Comment: I believe the correct command you want is `\mathup`, not `\mathrm`. I can't compile the MWE for come reason so I can't offer much help. How about loading `amsmath` and try `\operatorname{\theta}`?

Comment: @MobiusPizza Which package defines `\mathup` ? `\operatorname` calls `\mathrm`. Did you try them yourself ?!

Comment: @Aydin my bad, mathup is something related to unicode-math in XeTeX or LuaTex

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You might want to file a feature request to the developer of `newtxmath`; in the meantime you can change the definitions of the Greek lowercase letters.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[type1]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm} 

\makeatletter
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\alpha}{\mathord}{lettersA}{11}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\beta}{\mathord}{lettersA}{12}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\gamma}{\mathord}{lettersA}{13}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\delta}{\mathord}{lettersA}{14}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilon}{\mathord}{lettersA}{15}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\zeta}{\mathord}{lettersA}{16}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\eta}{\mathord}{lettersA}{17}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\theta}{\mathord}{lettersA}{18}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\iota}{\mathord}{lettersA}{19}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\kappa}{\mathord}{lettersA}{20}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\lambda}{\mathord}{lettersA}{21}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\mu}{\mathord}{lettersA}{22}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathord}{lettersA}{23}
\iftx@altnu
  \re@DeclareMathSymbol{\nu}{\mathord}{lettersA}{40}
\fi
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\xi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{24}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\pi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{25}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\rho}{\mathord}{lettersA}{26}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\sigma}{\mathord}{lettersA}{27}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\tau}{\mathord}{lettersA}{28}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\upsilon}{\mathord}{lettersA}{29}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\phi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{30}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\chi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{31}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\psi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{32}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\omega}{\mathord}{lettersA}{33}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilon}{\mathord}{lettersA}{34}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\vartheta}{\mathord}{lettersA}{35}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varpi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{36}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varrho}{\mathord}{lettersA}{37}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varsigma}{\mathord}{lettersA}{38}
\re@DeclareMathSymbol{\varphi}{\mathord}{lettersA}{39}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
What I get: $\theta \bm{\theta}$

What I want: $\uptheta \bm{\uptheta}$ 
\end{document}
```

Note that `\mathbf{\theta}` won't do any good, only Latin letters are affected by `\mathbf`.

[image]

---

You can also define `\mathup` and `\mathbfup`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[type1]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mathup}[1]{\begingroup\changegreek\mathrm{#1}\endgroup}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\mathbfup}[1]{\begingroup\changegreekbf\mathbf{#1}\endgroup}

\makeatletter
\def\changegreek{\@for\next:={%
  alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,kappa,lambda,mu,nu,xi,pi,rho,sigma,%
  tau,upsilon,phi,chi,psi,omega,varepsilon,vartheta,varpi,varrho,varsigma,varphi}%
  \do{\expandafter\let\csname\next\expandafter\endcsname\csname\next up\endcsname}}
\def\changegreekbf{\@for\next:={%
  alpha,beta,gamma,delta,epsilon,zeta,eta,theta,kappa,lambda,mu,nu,xi,pi,rho,sigma,%
  tau,upsilon,phi,chi,psi,omega,varepsilon,vartheta,varpi,varrho,varsigma,varphi}%
  \do{\expandafter\def\csname\next\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\bm\expandafter{\csname\next up\endcsname}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\mathup{d}\mathup{\theta}d\theta$

$\mathbfup{d}\mathbfup{\theta}\bm{d}\bm{\theta}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankx. How can I make this symbol declarations local? I don't want to change the appearance of `$\theta$`, but $\mathrm{\theta}$. I edited the MWE to be more clear.

Comment: @Aydin Sorry, but I don't understand: `\mathrm` *doesn't* work with Greek letters.

Comment: Yes it doesn't and I want it to work. `isomath` makes it working for greek letters but it has other problems. I can use any other command instead of `\mathrm`, e.g., `\upright{\theta}`. What I need is a solution to locally change the appereance of greek letters to be upright, but not globally. One idea is to redefine `\mathrm` to locally replace any command like `\theta` with `\uptheta`.

Comment: I modified the question and now it reflects my idea for a solution.

Comment: @Aydin They're both the same

Comment: @egreg Thank you very much. `mathup` and `mathbfup` are exactly what I need. They work smoothly and can be included in other macros. I just edited your `\mathbfup` commmand above to use `\bm{\mathrm{}}` instead of `\mathbf{}`.

Comment: @Aydin Why should `\bm{\mathrm{...}` be necessary instead of `\mathbf`? If you look closely, `\mathbfup` changes the meaning of the Greek letters to give `\bm{\alpha}` and so on.

Comment: @egreg `\bm\mathrm{}` works on all letters and fonts. I need `\mathbfup` to make every math upright and bold not just greek letters. Otherwise, I have to include it inside another `\bm{\mathrm{}` that would be absrud.

Comment: @egreg, And, why do you need `\changegreekbf` instead of `\changegreek\bm` that works for me?

Comment: @Aydin Sorry, but I don't understand: do the macros work? I think so.

Comment: @egreg, your macros work. But if you try `\mathbfup{h\theta}` you will get an upright `theta` with a slanted `h`, at least in my document. So, you need to do the small change. Moreover, I think you can reuse `\changegreek` instead of defining a separate bold version, that is however not imprtant.

Comment: @Aydin I get upright "h" and "theta". Doing `\bm` on multiletter input is not guaranteed to give good results, so I prefer keeping this version.

Comment: @egreg, Ok.... The purpose of this thing for me, is to define new macros `\vect` and `\mat` to convert all vector and matrix names into upright bold symbols in text or math. They can be greek or latin letters. I keep `\bm\mathrm` as it's the way that works for me. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

with `xelatex` or `lualatex` you can choose the french style for upright greek letters and have also commands for the bold one:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[math-style=french]{unicode-math}
\usepackage{libertine}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}
What I get: $\theta \mbftheta \alpha \mbfalpha\mbftheta$ \\

What I want: $\theta \alpha\beta \mbfmu$ 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not want to globally switch to upright greek letters. What is needed, is a solution to temporally switch between upright and slanted greek letters.

Comment: you can define an own math version `upgreek`. Then you can switch between upright and italic greek with `\mathversion{...}`