# Upright small greek via newtxmath without replacing the math font

Tags: fonts, greek, libertine, newtxmath

I am trying to conform to the International Standard ISO 80000-2. The `isomath` package does a nice job, but it does not solve the problem of the missing upright/roman small Greek letters, needed for pi, Kronecker delta and the Levi-Civita symbol. This can be achieved in many ways, but usually the resulting Greek letters are clearly of a different font than their italics counterpart ones (I'm using the standard Computer Modern font).

The following code implements a very nice upright delta (all greek letters can be achieved in a similar fashion).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\deltaup}{\mathord}{lettersA}{14}

\begin{document}
$\delta\deltaup$
\end{document}
```

That is, the above code declares the wanted macro `\deltaup` using the symbol font lettersA, which itself is loaded by `newtxmath`. This works correctly, but as an unwanted side effect, loading `newtxmath` replaces the used math font in the document, which I do not want to alter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the CBfonts by Claudio Beccari, that are based on the Computer Modern design.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc} % or OT1, if you prefer

\DeclareSymbolFont{upgreek}{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\deltaup}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`d}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\piup}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`p}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\epsilonup}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`e}

\begin{document}
$\delta\deltaup$

$\pi\piup$

$\varepsilon\epsilonup$
\end{document}
```

[image]

A less efficient solution that doesn't waste a math font family, is with `textalpha`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textalpha}

\newcommand{\deltaup}{\text{\textdelta}}
\newcommand{\epsilonup}{\text{\textepsilon}}
\newcommand{\piup}{\text{\textpi}}

\begin{document}
$\delta\deltaup$

$\pi\piup$

$\varepsilon\epsilonup$
\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

If you want to use the upright Greek used when `\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}` is loaded, then here's the trick

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\let\iftx@libertine\iftrue
\let\iftx@minion\iffalse
\def\ntxmath@scaled{s*[1.02]}
\makeatother
\DeclareSymbolFont{upgreek}{U}{ntxmia}{m}{it}
\SetSymbolFont{upgreek}{bold}{U}{ntxmia}{b}{it}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\deltaup}{\mathord}{upgreek}{14}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varepsilonup}{\mathord}{upgreek}{34}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\piup}{\mathord}{upgreek}{25}

\begin{document}
$\delta\deltaup$

$\pi\piup$

$\varepsilon\varepsilonup$
\end{document}
```

[image]

In my opinion the result is decidedly worse.

Comment: These solutions do not use the libertine font as requested. The pi looks fine, but the epsilon and especially the delta does not.

Comment: What do you mean? You said you wanted letters compatible with Computer Modern, which the NewTX aren't.

Comment: @jmd_dk I added the trick you want. Personally I wouldn't use it.

Comment: @egreg: I use the last trick you presented in my document, but how would you define all lowercase greek symbols with more`\DeclareMathSymbol` commands? I don't know where to look up the slot numbers you used here for `mathord`. Where do you get these from?

Comment: @lblb You can use the `fonttable` package for printing a table of the desired font.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks! The `fonttable` manual says I need the tfm file name to print the table using `\fonttable{name}`. Which of these tfm files do I need? https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/libertine/tfm . I can create a new question if this gets too complicated for the comment section.

Comment: @lblb You can use `\xfonttable` that accepts arguments like for `\DeclareSymbolFont`

Comment: @egreg: I got it working, thanks. Together with your other related answer, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/109814/75284, I have all the upright greek I need for now.