# Get old ''in'' `\in` symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

I would like to get the old 'in' (`\in`) symbol in `LaTeX`. You know, the symbol which is (very similar or equal to) the upright varepsilon. So I think to use in fact the upright greek letter epsilon. For that I need such a character. It is provided for example in the package `upgreek`, but, if ti was possible, I would like to import only the `upvarepsilon` glyph intead of using all the package. Whast would be the code for that?

And, there is a better way to get the old in symbol?

I know [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font), but I don't know how to use it to import the `upright epsilon`. I have also read the `package documentation`from `CTAN`, but `upgreek` has only 4 pages, so it doesn't explain too much about fonts and options.
Finally, I have tried to copy the definition line of the `\upvarepsilon` in my preamble, but it doesn't work, logically.

Anyway, here is the symbol I wan:

[image]

Thanks

PD: There are many questions about importing dingle elements from other `packages` and their hasn't been marked as duplicate.

Comment: I know that question, but i don't know how to use it to import the epsilon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a math alphabet to spare, you could do this, which will use more proper spacing:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}

\DeclareSymbolFont{greekroman}{LGR}{cmr}{m}{rs}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\in}{\mathrel}{greekroman}{"65}

\begin{document}
\( \varepsilon \in 3 \)
\end{document}
```

Comment: One question before to mark it as good:How can I know if ''I have a math alphabet to spare''? What do you mean?

Comment: [This](http://tex.loria.fr/ctan-doc/macros/latex/doc/html/fntguide/node17.html) explains it a bit, but basically in plain (La)TeX you have a max of 16 uses of `\DeclareSymbolFont` (including the default 3 or so standard uses). Some packages use a lot of these, some use none. In {Xe,Lua}(La)TeX I think you have practically infinite slots. As long as you don't get the error `LaTeX Error: Too many symbol fonts declared` you're good.

Comment: I see know.  However,  your code doesn't compile me.  I suppose LGR needs some special font that I haven't got installed. Anyway,  your answer is very good.

Comment: They're probably in the `cbfonts` package, which comes in a lot of shapes (e.g. the `{rs}` from above), as we can see in `lgrcmr.fd`.

Comment: I'll try and I'll post a comment.

Answer (score 4):

I’ve one book that uses ɛ for the relation “belongs to”, precisely Kelley’s “General Topology”. It’s old-fashioned, though.

You can use `\textgreek` for this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textgreek}

\renewcommand{\in}{\mathrel{\text{\textepsilon}}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\notin}{\mathrel{\vphantom{/}\mathpalette\dog@notin\relax}}
\newcommand{\dog@notin}[2]{%
  \ooalign{\hfil$\m@th#1/$\hfil\cr\hfil$\m@th#1\in$\hfil\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$x\in X$ $y\notin X$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know how to define the math relation. My problem is in importing the glyph. I was wonder because I found an answer of yours  here:https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203187/upright-small-greek-via-newtxmath-without-replacing-the-math-font?rq=1. The `\epsilon` I want is the `\varepslion` of your last option. However, it doesn't work. Do you know  why? Do you think I should change the question and ask why your answer doesn't work?

Comment: I must also confess that I knew how to define the math relation, but it seems define the `\notin` command is really difficult and probably I wouldn't know how to do it. So thanks.

Comment: @Dog_69 With the declaration of a new symbol font it's a bit more efficient, not much to care with today's machines.

Comment: \egreg: Right. Anyway, I would like to get the symbol of the picture (see the edit).

Comment: @Dog_69 Find a font that has the shape you'd like. I wouldn't care about the small difference.