# Upright, boldface, lowercase, greek math symbols with cbgreek glyphs

Tags: fonts, math-mode, greek

The standard math fonts in LaTeX do not include upright and upright boldface glyphs for lowercase greek symbols. Unfortunately, I need them in my document, so in some way I'll have to import the glyphs from another set of fonts. After looking through various sets of fonts in various packages, I have found that the Didot style set of fonts in the `cbgreek` sets of fonts will best fit my document. The problem is: I don't know how I can import the fonts I need and define selected glyphs as math symbols. I tried experimenting with [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30552/3465), but I wasn't able to load the correct font. An explanation on how to import `cbgreek` fonts and define selected glyphs as math symbols would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you need to do this?  As a first approximation "things that are difficult to do in LaTeX are difficult for a (typographic) reason".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way with a new math symbol font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}

\DeclareSymbolFont{upgreek}{LGR}{cmr}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{upgreek}{bold}{LGR}{cmr}{bx}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upalpha}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`a}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upbeta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`b}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upgamma}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`g}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\updelta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`d}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upepsilon}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`e}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upzeta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upeta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`h}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uptheta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`j}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upiota}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`i}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upkappa}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`k}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uplambda}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`l}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upmu}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`m}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upnu}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upxi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`x}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upomicron}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`o}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`p}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uprho}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`r}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upsigma}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`s}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uptau}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`t}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upupsilon}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`u}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upphi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`f}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upchi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\uppsi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\upomega}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`w}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upalpha}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upbeta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`B}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upgamma}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`G}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Updelta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`D}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upepsilon}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`E}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upzeta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`Z}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upeta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`H}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Uptheta}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`J}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upiota}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`I}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upkappa}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`K}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Uplambda}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`L}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upmu}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`M}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upnu}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`N}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upxi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`X}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upomicron}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`O}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Uppi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`P}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Uprho}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`R}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upsigma}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`S}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Uptau}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`T}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upupsilon}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`U}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upphi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`F}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upchi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`Q}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Uppsi}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`Y}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Upomega}{\mathord}{upgreek}{`W}

\begin{document}
$\upalpha\upbeta\upgamma\updelta\upepsilon\upzeta\upeta
\uptheta\upiota\upkappa\uplambda\upmu\upnu\upxi\upomicron\uppi
\uprho\upsigma\uptau\upupsilon\upphi\upchi\uppsi\upomega$

$\alpha\ne\upalpha\ne\bm{\upalpha}$

$\Gamma\ne\Upgamma\ne\bm{\Upgamma}$
\end{document}
```

Maybe you don't need the uppercase letters, but it was easy to add them.

[image]

Comment: The font ligature for sigma is quite annoying for math usages. Do you know how it can be suppressed when declaring sigma as a math symbol?

Comment: @FR09 What ligature are you referring to?

Comment: The font automatically turns the σ into a ς when it is not followed by a letter.

Comment: @FR09 Not in my experiments with the provided code. Are you using `\upsigma`?

Comment: Using your setup, $\upsigma$ and $\upsigma \alpha$ give different results for sigma.

Comment: @FR09 Sorry, I cannot reproduce: [picture (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbtAO.png) Please, open a new question with the details needed to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Sorry, I was using ```LuaLaTeX``` previously and forgot to switch back to ```pdfLaTeX```. Your setup works perfectly fine in ```pdfLaTeX```.

Comment: @FR09 Not really a good idea of the LuaTeX developers to enable ligatures in math fonts…