# Adjust custom made upright greek letters when used in subscripts

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, greek, letterspacing

I really like how Steven is [generating upright **greek letters**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230220/36835) in his answer:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2$}}

\newcommand\ualpha{\unslant\alpha}
\newcommand\ubeta{\unslant\beta}
\newcommand\ugamma{\unslant\gamma}

\begin{document}
$\alpha\beta\gamma$ \par
$\ualpha\ubeta\ugamma$ \par

$X_{\alpha\beta 123}$ \par
$X_{\ualpha\ubeta 123}$ \par
\end{document}
```

However, when it comes to subscripts, it just does not look right:

[image]

Especially the gap between the letters and the numbers looks bad and the come out way too big.

I experimented with

```
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2\!$}}
```

but now it comes out badly in normal text:

[image]

Is there any solution to get it work? Or do I need to define separate commands, for both cases subscripts and normal?

I'd like to avoid to return to packages like `upgreek`, which just doesn't fit a lot of fonts. But I didn't had these problems though.

---

Splitting up the definitions would work, not perfect but on could live with it:

```
\newcommand\ualpha{\unslant\alpha}
\newcommand\ubeta{\unslant\beta}
\newcommand\ugamma{\unslant\gamma}
\newcommand\sualpha{\scriptsize\unslant\alpha\kern-0.075em}
\newcommand\subeta{\scriptsize\unslant\beta\kern-0.07em}
\newcommand\sugamma{\scriptsize\unslant\gamma\kern-0.07em}

\begin{document}
$\alpha\beta\gamma$ \par
$\ualpha\ubeta\ugamma$ \par

$X_{\alpha\beta 123}$ \par
$X_{\sualpha\subeta 123}$ \par
\end{document}
```

[image]

But is that really necessary?

Comment: aside from the fact that this question specifies bold, the solution offered should work as well in your case: [Upright, boldface, lowercase, greek math symbols with cbgreek glyphs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/197574/579).  the change needed should be to replace the `bold` and `bx` in the line `\SetSymbolFont{upgreek}{bold}{LGR}{cmr}{bx}{n}]` by `U` and `m`.  (not tested.)

Comment: You could use \let\oldalpha=\alpha \def\alpha{\upslant{\oldalpha}} for every character.  You can put it in a separate file and use \input to load it in the preamble.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I don't see how this should solve my problem. I don't want to use the upgreek package and subscripts are not mentioned in your linked answer neither.

Comment: @JohnKormylo could you specify what you mean? My question contains a minimal working example. Also I don't see how it solves the problem with the subscripts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made two adjustments to your MWE

1. I did a small `\mkern` and minus `\mkern` around each character to better align them with the slanted counterparts; and
2. More importantly, I used the `\ThisStyle{...\SavedStyle...}` syntax of the `scalerel` package to preserve the math style of the argument.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{%
  \mkern1mu%
  \ThisStyle{\slantbox[#1]{$\SavedStyle#2$}}%
  \mkern-1mu%
}

\newcommand\ualpha{\unslant\alpha}
\newcommand\ubeta{\unslant\beta}
\newcommand\ugamma{\unslant\gamma}

\begin{document}
$\alpha\beta\gamma$ \par
$\ualpha\ubeta\ugamma$ \par

$X_{\alpha\beta 123}$ \par
$X_{\ualpha\ubeta 123}$ \par
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that \unslant put the unslanted character on the right edge of the space originally needed for the slanted version. The following variation centers the unspanted character in the same space.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newlength{\foodim}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \foodim=#1\wd\foobox
        \hskip \wd\foobox
        \hskip -0.5\foodim
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
        \hskip 0.5\foodim
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{\slantbox[#1]{$#2$}}

\let\oldalpha=\alpha
\def\alpha{\unslant{\oldalpha}}
\let\oldbeta=\beta
\def\beta{\unslant{\oldbeta}}
\let\oldgamma=\gamma
\def\gamma{\unslant{\oldgamma}}

\begin{document}
$\alpha\beta\gamma$ \par

$X_{\alpha\beta 123}$ \par
\end{document}
```

[image: unslandted greek]

Comment: In this answer the subscripts have the same size as the normal letters. Thats not the idea. Apart from that, the answer is practically identical to the accepted one?

Comment: I just used and referenced your answer at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239791/is-this-laplace-transform-symbol-available-in-latex/239796#239796

Comment: @thewaywewalk John's answer adds value to my own answer in that he achieves the horizontal spacing correction directly inside the `\slantbox`, rather than relying on an externally applied `\mkern` as I do.  I take his answer as a suggested improvement to my own, though you are correct in pointing out he does not preserve the math style.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I see! But I could just combine both answer, right?

Comment: It was originally posted April 5 to the wrong question.  I was just moving it to the right question.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Yes, you can combine the best of both.