# Theta hat dot: upright and bold

Tags: greek

I've had endless problems trying to get bold, upright theta symbol, with a bold hat on top, and an ordinary dot on top of that.

I got most of the way, minus the dot, using the following code: (I got the unslanted theta code from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236915/adjust-custom-made-upright-greek-letters-when-used-in-subscripts))

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
    \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
    \hskip\wd\foobox
    \pdfsave
    \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
    \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
    \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{%
    \mkern1mu%
    \ThisStyle{\slantbox[#1]{$\SavedStyle#2$}}%
    \mkern-1mu%
}
\newcommand{\utheta}{\unslant\theta}

\begin{document}
    $\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\hat{\utheta}}}$
\end{document}
```

This gives me an output of everything I want, except an ordinary dot on top:

[image]

As soon as I wrap the existing code in `\dot{}`, things go haywire, with error messages including lots of `@` symbols, which I assume means I *really* messed something up. If anyone has a solution to this, it'd be much appreciated!

**Things I don't want:**

- A solution involving upgreek, since non-symmetrical versions of theta like that look ugly to me.
- The code `$\boldsymbol{\mathrm{\dot{\hat{\utheta}}}}$` isn't what I'm looking for, since the dot is bold.
- Please no `pmb`.
- Solutions involving a change of font. I'm sticking with Computer Modern for this project.

Comment: Is that hat centred over the theta?  It looks slightly right of centre to me.  (Maybe that is the desired outcome.)

Comment: It's not, but involving kerning would've made the question more complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stack a dot on top.  The gap (currently `.5pt`) is adjustable with the optional argument to `\stackon`.  EDITED to take Mico's advice (except with +/-1.3 mu instead of 1.5).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{scalerel,stackengine}
\stackMath

\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
    \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
    \hskip\wd\foobox
    \pdfsave
    \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
    \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
    \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{%
    \mkern1.3mu%
    \ThisStyle{\slantbox[#1]{$\SavedStyle#2$}}%
    \mkern-1.3mu%
}
\newcommand{\utheta}{\mathord{\unslant\theta}}

\begin{document}
    $\boldsymbol{\hat{\utheta}}$
and this
    $\stackon[.5pt]{\boldsymbol{\hat{\utheta}}}{.}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Two suggestions: First, instead of deploying `\mathrm`, set `\newcommand{\utheta}{\mathord{\unslant\theta}}`. Second, increase the arguments of `\mkern` to 1.5mu and -1.5mu, respectively, to get better centering of `\utheta` below the stacked accents.

Comment: @Mico Done...except used 1.3mu, since I felt 1.5mu overcompensated.

Comment: It works like a charm :) Thanks a lot! I'll fiddle with the kerning myself till it looks decent.

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you load both the `upgreek` (gulp...) and `bm` packages along with `amsmath` and write something along the lines of the code shown below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,upgreek,bm}
\begin{document}
$\dot{\bm{\hat{\uptheta}}}, 
 \dot{\hat{\uptheta}}, 
 \dot{\hat{\theta}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I specifically don't want upgreek's ugly thetas.

Comment: @Jean-JacqduPlessis - I did notice your aversion to the `upgreek` package in your initial posting. I chose to provide this answer anyway as it may be of interest to other readers of your posting. You are, of course, entirely free to disregard it.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\newsavebox{\foobox}
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][0]{\mbox{%
    \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
    \hskip\wd\foobox
    \pdfsave
    \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
    \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
    \pdfrestore
}}
\newcommand\unslant[2][-.25]{%
    \mkern1mu%
    \ThisStyle{\slantbox[#1]{$\SavedStyle#2$}}%
    \mkern-1mu%
}
\newcommand{\utheta}{\unslant\theta}

\begin{document}


    $\dot{\boldsymbol{\hat{{\utheta}}}}$ $\boldsymbol{\dot{\hat{{\utheta}}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: How does your answer differ (meaningfully) from Steven's? (I realize that writing `{\utheta}`, i.e., encasing `\utheta` in curly braces) is the same as defining the symbol to be of type `mathord`. )

Comment: @Mico ??? It's completely different isn't it?  I place the dot using `\dot{xxx}` Steven uses `\stackon[.5pt]{xxx}{.}` not using the mathaccent primitive at all.

Comment: You're right. I had mistakenly focused on the code for `\unslant` and `\slantbox` (which came, via the OP, from another answer of Steven's).

Comment: @DavidCarlislel to be fair, misunderstandings like Mico's are expected when "mic-drop" answers like this one don't supply any discussion or context beyond the  code.

Comment: Thanks, but this solution doesn't answer the question, as the dot is bold, which causes an inconsistency with other dots.

Comment: @Jean-JacqduPlessis ?????? the one on the right is bold, for comparison, I was suggesting you use the code on the left which is clearly not bold.

Comment: Apologies, I had a brain fart :-) I've already implemented Steven's solution, but I will look at your solution sometime since it looks simpler.