# Using siunitx, \ohm results in an italic Omega

Tags: siunitx

The title basically says it all.

I use `siunitx` with

```
\usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE}
```

For `\SI{...}{\micro\ohm}`, the `\micro` is output correctly (non-italic), and `\ohm` is output in italic. This happens both in text and in math mode.

My MWE is

```
\documentclass{publisher-custom}
\usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE}

\begin{document}
\SI{1,09715247}{\micro\ohm}
\end{document}
```

How can I fix this as I'm unable to change (or post here) what's in the publisher's custom document class code?

**Update:**

I found these lines in the publisher's cls file grep'ing for [Oo]mega:

```
...
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"0A}
...
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varOmega}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"0A}
...
```

Does that help?

Comment: You _really_ should post a MWE here: I can't reproduce your output. Plus, the macro you should use is `\micro`, not plain `\mu`.

Comment: Without the class `publisher-custom` the MWE will already on the first line. If you cannot make the class available, then use a standard class and add the stuff of the class, which is needed to reproduce the problem. My first guess would be font related stuff.

Comment: Try if you can do `%\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"0A}` (comment out that line)! If you can still compile, you are good to go.

Comment: LaRiFaRi: That works, but I need a solution that does not tinker with the cls file.

Comment: What about `\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"0A}` then? Seems to be a duplicate of [Force upright Greek letters with isomath](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/30550/35864)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Answer to the updated question

The special class file uses:

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"0A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varOmega}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"0A}
```

Then `\Omega` is italics by default and `\varOmega` upright.
Package `siunitx` uses `\upOmega`, if it is available to initialize the symbol for `math-ohm`, otherwise `\Omega` is used as `\text{$\Omega$}`, which results in an italics *Ω*. Whereas `\mathrm{\Omega}` would have given an upright Ω.

Since the upright ohm symbol is available as `\varOmega`, the macro `\upOmega` can be provided easily for package `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"0A}% italics
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varOmega}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"0A}% upright
\providecommand*{\upOmega}{\varOmega}% for siunitx
\usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE}

\begin{document}
  \SI{1,09715247}{\micro\ohm}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Answer to the [first version](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/262332/1) of the question

I get an italic `\mu`. Probably you want to have `\micro` instead. The `\ohm` is upright:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[binary-units=true]{siunitx}
\sisetup{locale = DE}
\begin{document}
\si{\mu\ohm} vs.\@ \si{\micro\ohm}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: `\usepackage{lmodern}` would be nice here.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Why? Basically I get the same result. Also I did not want to add additional font packages to keep the example minimal. I suspect some problem with the fonts, which are used by the OP.

Comment: Just zoom in and take a look on the `\micro`. But, never mind. You got my vote. Let's wait for the OP's update.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi If I compare the result of `\showlists`, then there are tiny changes in the bounding box of `\micro`, but the shape looks pretty much the same with the ugly serifs, especially at the bottom.

Comment: Hmmm, I am getting a completely pixeled `\mu` when zooming in. Strange. Well, that's details.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi which LaTeX dist?

Comment: @daleif MiKTeX 2.9 (on Win7)

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Are you using `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` without package `cm-super` installed?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek No, just your MWE. Nothing else.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I see, `siunitx` already uses `T1` encoding, thus you need to install `cm-super`.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi Correction: `TS1` encoding, of course (the uppercase S was on vacation). Slot 181 contains the upright `\textmu`, which `siunitx` uses as micro sign. MiKTeX does not install `cm-super` on the fly automatically, because the fonts are not missing (strictly speaking).

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks for this information. I had no idea about that missing font.

Answer (score 3):

The designer of your document-class wants you to have italic upper-case Greeks which in my eyes is desirable according to ISO (but of course a matter of taste).

As your template is written as it is, I would not change this behaviour as I have suggested in comment. Just redefine the `math-ohm` from `siunitx` like so:

```
% arara: pdflatex

%\documentclass{publisher-custom}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{%
    ,binary-units=true
    ,locale = DE
    ,math-ohm  =\Omega
    }
\usepackage{lmodern}
% from your class definition
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Omega}{\mathalpha}{letters}{"0A}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\varOmega}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"0A}


\begin{document}
\si{\micro\ohm} and $\si{\micro\ohm}$ but $\mu\times\Omega$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That works! But I fail to comprehend why it does. According to the siunitx documentation, `math-ohm` is by default defined to `\Omega`.

Comment: Me neither, to be honest. @JosephWright